# Возврат массива из функции в обратном порядке

Tags: java, массивы

Задача: отправить в функицию массив и вернуть (не отобразить, а именно вернуть) массив в обратном порядке.

Результат: Вылазит ексепшн, согласно которому программа пытается обратится к элементу за пределами массива. Не могу понять где и почему это происходит?

```java
public class UserArray {
    static int[] myReverse(int[] Array) {
        int[] newArray = new int[Array.length];
        int size = Array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Array.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = Array[size];
            size = size - 1;
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program-ReverseArray");
        int[] Array = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3};
        int[] newArray = myReverse(Array);
        for (int i = 0; i <= newArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(newArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Между делом: имена локальных переменных [рекомендуется](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names) начинать с маленькой буквы. Еще, в стандартной библиотеке уже есть класс [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html), и использование этого названия для других сущностей сбивает с толку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int size = Array.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ошибка в данных строках:

```
newArray[i] = Array[size];
size = size - 1;
```

А должно быть:

```
newArray[i] = Array[(size - 1) - i];
```

Если Вы используете среду разработки, то она Вам должна была подсказать проблемные строки.

Answer (score 0):

`arr.length` - возвращает длину массива, т. е. в данном случае `4`. Индексы в массиве начинаются с `0`, т. е. последний элемент `3`. Надо добавить `-1`. Код может выглядеть так:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3};
    int[] arr2 = myReverse(arr1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [3, 2, 1, 0]
}

static int[] myReverse(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .map(i -> arr[arr.length - 1 - i])
            .toArray();
}
```